# GAS　高速道路渋滞・事故について

Tags: javascript

以下のページに掲載されているYahooの高速道路渋滞・事故情報を取得したいです。

https://roadway.yahoo.co.jp/traffic/urbanexway/1/road/2005012/list

条件としては規制区間に通行止めなどの文字が表示されましたら、メッセージをSNSにとばします。
GASにてプログラム作成しましたが、SNSにメッセージがいかないです。
デバッグモードで回してもエラー通知がないです。
お手数ですが、ご確認お願い致します。

スクリプト内容

```js
function trainlate() {

var currentDate = new Date();
var weekday = currentDate.getDay();
var date = Utilities.formatDate( currentDate, 'Asia/Tokyo', 'M月d日 HH時mm分');

if (weekday == 0 || weekday == 6) {
    return;
}
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('ja.japanese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com');
  if (calendar.getEventsForDay(currentDate, {max: 1}).length > 0) {
    return;
  }

  //fukutoshinsen line info
  var yahoodata = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://roadway.yahoo.co.jp/traffic/area/3/road/1035005/list").getContentText();
  if(yahoodata.indexOf('通行止') > -1){
    // match the word
  }else{    
    //get error info
    var yahoodatastart = yahoodata.indexOf('og:description" content="');
    //4 japanese word only
    yahoodatastart += 25;
    var yahoodataend = yahoodata.indexOf('通行止');
    var yahoodataoutput = yahoodata.substring(yahoodatastart, yahoodataend);

    postMessage("\n" + "◆1号羽田線の事故・渋滞情報 " + date + yahoodataoutput + "\n",'https://wh.jandi.com/connect-api/webhook/13433430/3067202d88fa96872cabd683ef33810a');

  }

}

function postMessage(message, hookPoint){
    var payload = {
      "body": message,
    }
    var options = {
      "method": "POST",
      "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/vnd.tosslab.jandi-v2+json",
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      }
    }
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(hookPoint, options);

    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      return response;
    }
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: `Logger.log` などを使い、「Yahooから情報を取得するだけ」及び「ハードコートされた適当なデータをSNSに投稿するだけ」のそれぞれのどちらが出来ていないのか確認してみてください。

Comment: Yahooから情報を取得するだけの部分になります。